Solving the Stochastic Differential Equation $dY_{t}=(a(t)Y(t)+b(t)\sqrt{Y_{t}}+c(t))\: dt + \sqrt{Y_{t}} dW_{t}$
Any ideas on how to solve this SDE? Or rather receive an explicit solution (possibly only for time-independent coefficients)?
$$d(X_{t})^{2} = 2 X_{t} dX_{t} + dX_{t} dX_{t} = (a(t)(X_{t})^{2}+b(t)X_{t}+c(t))\: dt + d(t) X_{t} dW_{t}$$
Or rewritten as
$$dY_{t}=(a(t)Y(t)+b(t)\sqrt{Y_{t}}+c(t))\: dt + \sqrt{Y_{t}} dW_{t}$$
We assume a simple $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ setting with Brownian motion $W$.

Have you tried to set $Y_t = X_t^2$ and use $dY_t = 2X_t dX_t + d(t) dt$?

I‘m not quite sure what you mean, could you explain?

The presence of the term $\sqrt{Y_{t}}dW_{t}$ makes this quite tricky. For example, the CIR process doesn't have any closed-form solution.
If you simply had the term $\sqrt{Y_{t}}dt$, then as mentioned here how to do such stochastic integration $dS = a S^b dt + c S dW$? you can obtain a linear differential equation.
In terms of existence and uniqueness, you can use the standards results by Yamada-Watanabe e.g. see here How to construct the strong solution to the SDE $dX_{t}=\sqrt{X_{t}}dW_{t}$?.
